# Primeng p-table - Show data instead of id

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, p-table

Is there a way in p-table to show the value instead of Id?

Eg: I get the data from server as below

```
[
   {row_id: 1, customer_id: 25, status: 'NEW'},
   {row_id: 1, customer_id: 26, status: 'NEW'},
]
```

I want to replace the customer id with customer name in the p-table with shows above data. I have the mapping of customer id to customer name as below

```
[
   {rowid: 25, name: 'Vinod'},
   {row_id: 26, name: 'Ram'}
]
```

**Edit**
I achieved this using Angular Pipe. But is there a p-table way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep you mapping array as below instead.

```
this.mapping = {
   25: {name: 'Vinod', age: 25},
   26: {name: 'Ram'}
}
```

and in your html as below.

```
<td>mapping[rowData['customer_id']].name</td>
```